# Как проверить есть ли у двух строк хотя бы одно общее слово?

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Ситуация следующая. Хочу сделать сравнение строк на входящие в них слова. Если есть слово в одной строке и это же слово есть в другой - то выдать `true`.

Есть ли стандартные способы такого сравнения?

Имеется в виду, что строки сравниваются пословно. Единственное что сам надумал это разбить строки на слова с помощью `str.Split()` и циклом перебирать.

А если конкретнее: В базе есть наименование организации. И эти же организации присылают файлы со своим именем или же кто-то переименовывает криво именованный файл на нормальный. И чтобы сильно не зависеть от того, как пере/именовали файл то сравнивать пословно название организации из БД и из имени файла, так как одно из слов соответствует сокращенному имени организации.

Например, есть наименование "ООО МТР МОСКВА" (рандомное имя). и есть файл с именем "отчет от МТР" и нужно подтверждение, что у строк есть общее слово "МТР".

Comment: Если вам надо понять, насколько 2 строки похожи друг на друга, то я вам предлагаю измерить [расстояние между строками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), чем разбивать их на слова и сравнивать слова.

Comment: @tym32167 нет строки довольно разные, просто на случай изменения имени организации или добавлением оной я хочу сделать связкой select из базы (получил список организаций) -> получить имя файла -> разбить на слова -> сравнить слова. ТО етсь не зависеть от человека кто и как именует файлы но они в любом случае будут содержать сокращенное имя для удобства.

Comment: Я и со второго раза не понял, что вам надо. Гораздо проще будет привести примеры, что конкретно на входе, что на выходе, что хотите в алгоритме сделать.

Comment: например, в сравниваемых множествах слова привести к одному регистру `String.ToUpperInvariant()` и найти их (подмножество) [пересечение Enumerable.Intersect( )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Alias Почти подходит но не совсем то. Попробовал - это выдает мне коллекцию символов входящих в обе строки. то есть мне нужно собирать символы в слово и снова искать получившееся слово в искомой строке и проверять есть ли такое или нету с помощью Contains(). А нужно слово целиком либо null - нашлись слова или не нашлись или так же как Contains(). Но все равно спасибо за идею.

Comment: @tym32167 ну например в БД есть строка с именем "ООО МТР МОСКВА" (рандомное имя). и есть файл с именем "отчет от МТР" и нужно подтверждение ест ли это "МТР" во второй строке или нету.

Comment: этот результат может быть только если строку разбил не на слова, а на символы :) покажи свой код со `String.Split()`, у него параметром должен быть массив символов-разделителей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Насколько я понял, требуется возвращать `true` если в строках есть хотя бы одно общее, полностью совпадающее слово. Т.е. для этих строк результат будет `true`:

```
"ООО МТР МОСКВА", "отчет от МТР"
"ООО МТР МОСКВА", "мтр"
"ООО МТР МОСКВА", "ООО Рога и копыта"
"ООО МТР МОСКВА", "Москва златоглавая"
```

, а для этих — `false`:

```
"ООО МТР МОСКВА", "отчет от МТС"
"ООО МТР МОСКВА", "мт"
"ООО МТР МОСКВА", "Москвашвея"
"ООО МТР МОСКВА", "ООО1"
```

Если Вам требуется другое поведение, то уточните условие.

Не думаю, что для этого есть стандартный способ, но есть несколько вариантов реализации.

### Вариант 1. Регулярное выражение.

Можно соединить строки, а затем проверить наличие общего слова регулярным выражением:

```
//регулярное выражение нечувствительное к регистру
private static readonly Regex COMMON_WORD_REGEX =
    new Regex(@"(\b\S+\b).*#(?=.*\1)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

private static bool HaveCommonWord(string s1, string s2)
{
    //соединяем строки символом, который отсутствует в обеих строках
    var concatenated = s1 + "#" + s2;
    //проверяем с помощью регулярного выражения встречается ли одно и то же слово
    //по обе стороны от «специального» символа «#»
    return COMMON_WORD_REGEX.IsMatch(concatenated);
}
```

Разбор регулярного выражения по частям:

```
(\b\S+\b) — какое-то слово (первая группа — \1)
.*        — какие-то символы
#         — #, символ-разделитель не встречающийся в строках
(?=.*\1)  — слово \1 в оставшейся части строки
```

Обратите внимание, что слова разделяются по границам слов, т.е. по любому неалфавитно-цифровому символу. Если нужно другое разделение, то добавьте ограничения в группу слова: `\b\S+\b`

### Вариант 2. Разбиение на слова.

Действуем напрямую: разбиваем первое слово на слова, создаем множество слов и проверяем все слова из первой строки.

```
 private static bool HaveCommonWord(string s1, string s2)
 {
      var words = new HashSet<String>(s1.Split(), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
      return s2.Split().Any(words.Contains);
 }
```

Если первая строка будет всегда одной и той же, то можно переиспользовать созданное множество.

Обратите внимание, что строки деляться на слова по пробельным символам. В комментариях @Alias приводит пример строк "Gmbh 'Gebbels&Sons'" и "Sons", для которых метод вернет false. Если нужно делить слова не только по пробельным символам, передайте в `Split` символы для разделения, либо воспользуйтесь [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Оптимизация

Для улучшения производительности можно попробовать создать некий поисковый индекс:

1. пройтись по всем организациям, разбить каждую на слова, либо сопоставить каждой слово;
2. на основе этого составить словарь ключом в котором будет слово, а значением — список организаций;
3. каждую искомую строку разбивать на слова и проверять каждое слово по словарю, для слова по которому есть хотя бы одна организация возвращать результат.

Словарь «слово → организации» придется построить один раз. После этого поиск организаций по общему слову будет работать быстро.

Если организации хранятся в БД, то возможно будет быстрее построить SQL-запрос на основе искомой строки.

Comment: а для строк "Gmbh 'Gebbels&Sons' " и "Sons"? мне кажется, зря в качество разделителей ограничились только пробелами по умолчанию :)

Comment: @Alias согласен, хороший пример. Но это уже автору вопроса нужно уточнить что именно считается словом, а что нет. Попробую упомянуть о разделителях в ответе, спасибо!

Comment: @Alias Да есть и названия типа "МТР-Плюс" поэтому разделитель не обязательно такой, но это неважно и я бы догадался)

Comment: @defaultlocale большое спасибо! взял ваш вариант.

Comment: @Ackbar Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

я вижу 2 варианта:

1) Выполнить запрос в БД

```
SELECT * FROM Organizations
WHERE Name LIKE '%отчет%'
  OR column1 LIKE '%от%'
  OR column1 LIKE '%МТР%'
```

и результаты запроса проверять по методу @default_locale

2) Если операция частая, а не разовая, то можно добавить табличку в БД для слов названий организаций

```
--------------------------
| id  | OrgId   | Word   |
--------------------------
| 1   | 10      | ООО    |
| 2   | 10      | МТР    |
| 3   | 10      | МОСКВА |
```

Тогда все становится так:

```
SELECT distinct o.* 
FROM Organizations o 
    JOIN OrganizationsWords w 
    ON o.id=w.orgId
WHERE w.word like 'отчет'
  OR  w.word like 'от'
  OR  w.word like 'МТР'
```

Comment: не подойдет так как "ооо мтр москва" хранится одним полем в базе но всеравно спасибо

Comment: @Ackbar Номер 1 именно про вариант с 1 полем в БД

Comment: Строку (имя файла) для сравнения в LIKE опять же придется разбивать на слова. Думаю это сложнее чем на c# но как вариант спасибо. Буду искать.

Comment: @Ackbar да, её разбивать полюбому, чтобы было что искать